# Outlook 2003 - Inbox search results are not chronologicaly displayed

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

I am performing a search in my Inbox (22500 items) and when I search for the word "Juris", it doesn't show the newest email to the oldest ones... It starts on March 22nd by example then I get older emails displayed but not the latest ones...

Is this is something that can be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is crazy, the fix must be done every time you do a search ... when the results are finished, right click on the list view column header name (say From for example) and choose "Customize Current View" then choose "Fields" then choose "Received" or "Sent" as desired. I think Outlook 2007 has more fields shown by default.